# references on an aspx page, ashx page causing error in a report viewer declaration

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, razor

I have built a Web Matrix site using VB.NET. I added a file called reports.aspx to handle some reporting. Specifically, it uses the Neodynamic Web Client Print SDK to save a report from SSRS to PDF then redirects to a handler file called reports.ashx that actually handles the printing.

Code from reports.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" %>
<%-- Register the WebClientPrint script code --%>
 <%=Neodynamic.SDK.Web.WebClientPrint.CreateScript(MyUtils.GetWebsiteRoot() + "reports.ashx")%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script language="VB" runat="server">
Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim reportname As String
    Dim paramBlock As New ReportParameter()
    Dim paramID As New ReportParameter()

    reportname = Request("reportname")
    Dim v As New ReportViewer
    v.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
    Dim serverreport As New ServerReport
    serverreport = v.ServerReport
    serverreport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://websql1.core.com/Reports")
    serverreport.ReportPath = "/Reports/Aramid/Sheeter/" & reportname

    Select Case reportname

    Case Is = "NomexBlockCard" Or "NomexBlockLabel" Or "NomexInternalLabel"
        paramBlock.Name = "paramBlock"
        paramBlock.Values.Add(Request("paramBlock"))
        Dim parameters() As ReportParameter = {paramBlock}
    Case Is = "NomexRoutingData"
        paramID.Name = "paramID"
        paramID.Values.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Request("paramID")))
        Dim parameters() As ReportParameter = {paramID}
    End Select

    serverreport.SetParameters(parameters)

    Save(serverreport, "~/Files/")

    'now print
    Response.Redirect("reports.ashx?fileName=" & reportname)

End Sub

Public Sub Save(ByVal sr As ServerReport, ByVal savePath As String)
    Dim Bytes() As Byte = sr.Render("PDF", "", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
    Using Stream As New FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create)
        Stream.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length)
    End Using
End Sub


</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Code from reports.ashx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="reports" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports Neodynamic.SDK.Web

Public Class reports : Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    Dim useDefaultPrinter As Boolean = True '(context.Request("useDefaultPrinter") = "checked")
    Dim printerName As String = context.Server.UrlDecode(context.Request("printerName"))

    Dim fileName As String = context.Server.UrlDecode(context.Request("fileName"))
    Dim filePath As String = "~/Files/"

    If (filePath <> Nothing) Then

        Dim file As New PrintFile(context.Server.MapPath(filePath), fileName)
        Dim cpj As New ClientPrintJob()
        cpj.PrintFile = file
        If (useDefaultPrinter OrElse printerName = "null") Then
            cpj.ClientPrinter = New DefaultPrinter()
        Else
            cpj.ClientPrinter = New InstalledPrinter(printerName)
        End If
        cpj.SendToClient(context.Response)

    End If

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

When I open Visual Studio to build and publish, I get the following error.

"*import of type system.web.httpcontextbase from assembly of module system.web failed*"

When I look at the code in reports.aspx, there is an error under the line

```
Dim v as New ReportViewer
```

The error correction option says that  "*reference is required to System.Web.Extensions version = 3.5.0.0,.... containing the implemented interface System.Web.UI.IScriptControl. Add one to your project*"

I am referencing System.Web, System.Web.Extensions, and System.Web.Abstractions.

Targeting .NET 4

Please help me to understand this issue or what needs to be looked at.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be something very simple. While I started the project in Webmatrix, as it grew I moved it to a Visual Studio solution. When I moved it to a solution it changed the target framework to 2.0 rather than 4.

Strange. Changed the target back to 4, updated the references and good to go!